# How to Push Saved Docker Image File to Registry using Docker-SDK?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, docker-registry

I have numerous saved an Images in my HD using `$ docker save`.

I am trying to Push this to Docker Registry, but Docker-SDK only allows me to Push Repositories and not the Image Files.

```py
for line in cli.push('username/project', stream=True, decode=True):
   print(line)
```

Answer (score 2):

Need to load the image then tag it, then push

```
docker load -i YOUR_DOCKER_TAR
docker images (look for your image you just loaded)
docker tag IMAGE:TAG REPO_URL:PORT/IMAGE:TAG (e.g docker tag test:latest 127.0.0.1:5000/test:latest)
docker push REPO_URL:PORT/IMAGE:TAG
```